# Close button for mobile menu with sticky :hover

Tags: css, hover, sticky

Any hints on how to create a button to close a CSS-only menu that is left open with a sticky :hover on a mobile device would be truly appreciated.

Example to view on mobile is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text)

Goal: I'm trying to add a simple close button that is automatically displayed on a mobile device but I'm having trouble with using :after or :before on hover as it is still tied to the sticky hover menu.

The only option for a user to close the menu is to tap somewhere else on the screen but this is less intuitive due to size of the final menu and screen space.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use jquery  `window();` onclick  in the mobile device.

Comment: Thx Meraj, I have tried various methods with Jquery and CSS but on mobile/iOS, it appears the hover sticks until a different area of the screen is tapped. Toggling css via Jquery does not appear to undo the hover as well. I have instead opted to remove the hover for smaller screens and use Jquery css toggle.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on my site, using bootstrap.